# Extracting I frames & DC coefficents

Tags: mpeg-4

How do I extract I frames & DC coefficients from an MPEG-4 video?

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the I frames the use ffmpeg to extract them. You can use the -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" option to get only the I pictures out.  To get the dc coeffs you will have to modify the decoder source code to get it out. I don't think you will directly find a tool to give it to you.

Comment: thanks for this, could you plz write the complete command to get an I frame from (test.mp4) because iam trying but it not work ?

Comment: i have the following command but still error ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select="eq(pict_type\, PICT_TYPE_I)" I-Frm-%03d.jpeg

Comment: Try only I instead of PICT_TYPE_I

Comment: This worked for me: Gave me a I pictures only formed video: ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vsync 0  -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)"  -an -vcodec mpeg4 out.mp4. You can do the same and get jpegs if you want.

Comment: "ffmpeg -i test1.mp4  -vsync 0 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)" -an  -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg " this command works ,NOW i will search how to get DC coefficients , wish me luck & thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using this command I'm able to extract the I-frames

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf "select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)'" -vsync vfr thumb%04d.png
```